# $\text{Cov}(\max(X,Y), \max(X, Z)) \leq \text{Var}(X)$

Tags: probability-theory, covariance

Given three independent random variables $X, Y, Z$, is it true that
$$\text{Cov}(\max(X,Y), \max(X, Z)) \leq C \cdot \text{Var}(X)?$$

I am thinking about the case where the $\text{Var}(Y)$ and $\text{Var}(Z)$ are much larger than $\text{Var}(X)$, so Cauchy-Schwartz inequality would not be useful here.

My gut feeling this should hold because of the independence. I tried a few conditioning. For example, we know $\max(X, Z)\perp Y$, so if we condition on $Y$, we have
$$\text{Cov}(\max(X,Y), \max(X, Z)) = \mathbb{E}[\text{Cov}_{\mathcal{F}_Y}(\max(X,Y), \max(X, Z))].$$
I also tried conditioning on $X$, but these did not lead to anything at this moment.

Comment: @SangchulLee We are assuming that $X, Y, Z$ are independent.

Comment: Oops, you are right. I somehow forgot that $Y$ and $Z$ are assumed to be independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\widetilde{Y} = \max\{Y, X\}$ and $\widetilde{Z} = \max\{Z, X\}$ for brevity. Then by the [law of total covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance),

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Cov}(\widetilde{Y}, \widetilde{Z})
&= \mathbf{E}[\overbrace{ \mathbf{Cov}(\widetilde{Y}, \widetilde{Z} \mid X) }^{=0}] + \mathbf{Cov}(\mathbf{E}[\widetilde{Y} \mid X], \mathbf{E}[\widetilde{Z} \mid X]) \\
&= \mathbf{Cov}(f(X), g(X)),
\end{align*}

where $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are defined by

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \mathbf{E}[\widetilde{Y} \mid X = x] = \mathbf{E}[\max\{Y, x\}], \\
g(x) &= \mathbf{E}[\widetilde{Z} \mid X = x] = \mathbf{E}[\max\{Z, x\}].
\end{align*}

Now we note that both $f$ and $g$ are $1$-Lipschitz, since $x \mapsto \max\{y, x\}$ is $1$-Lipschitz for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$. To make use of this observation, we need the following result:

> **Lemma.** Let $X \in L^2(\mathbf{P})$, and let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $L$-Lipschitz. Then
> $$ \mathbf{Var}(f(X)) \leq L^2 \mathbf{Var}(X). $$
>
> *Proof.* We adopt the symmetrization trick. Let $X'$ be an i.i.d. copy of $X$. Then
> \begin{align*}
> \mathbf{Var}(f(X))
> = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{E}[(f(X) - f(X'))^2]
> \leq \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{E}[L^2 (X - X')^2]
> = L^2 \mathbf{Var}(X).
> \end{align*}

So by the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and the above lemma,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Cov}(\widetilde{Y}, \widetilde{Z})
\leq \sqrt{\mathbf{Var}(f(X))\mathbf{Var}(g(X))}
\leq \mathbf{Var}(X).
\end{align*}

Therefore OP's claim holds with $C = 1$.

---

**Addendum.** By the Harris inequality and the monotonicity of $f$ and $g$, we also have

$$ \mathbf{Cov}(\widetilde{Y}, \widetilde{Z}) \geq 0. $$

This shows that the magnitude of the covariance $\mathbf{Cov}(\widetilde{Y}, \widetilde{Z})$ is bounded by the variance of $X$.